# how can i add style with CSS to <script> with no #id or .class?

Tags: jquery, css

i have some problems displaying some advertising, cause some of them are generated by JS and some are simple `<a>`,

how could I identify any  inside, for example #my_adds box list `<div>` ?

IF not, any easy solution in Jquery to select first `<p>` after an `<script>` ?

Case i want to intercept:

```
<td colspan="2" valign="top">                                <h5>ThePhoneHouse</h5>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var uri = 'http://impes.tradedoubler.com/imp?type(img)g(18440980)a(1871028)' + new String (Math.random()).substring (2, 11);
document.write('<a href="http://clk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=75510&a=1871028&g=18440980" mce_href="http://clk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=75510&amp;a=1871028&amp;g=18440980" target="_BLANK"><img src="'+uri+'" mce_src="'+uri+'" border=0 vspace="25"></a>');
// ]]></script><a href="http://clk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=75510&amp;a=1871028&amp;g=18440980" mce_href="http://clk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=75510&amp;a=1871028&amp;g=18440980" target="_BLANK"><img src="http://impes.tradedoubler.com/imp?type%28img%29g%2818440980%29a%281871028%29142438581" mce_src="http://impes.tradedoubler.com/imp?type(img)g(18440980)a(1871028)142438581" border="0" vspace="25"></a>
<p>Telefonía, Cámaras Digitales, Televisores, toda la electrónica en PhoneHouse</p>
<p>PARA CANJEAR TU BONO: Aplicación automática, solo por registrarte en el boletín de ofertas, llévate 10€ de descuento para tus compras*</p>
<p><a href="#"></a></p>
<hr size="1"> </td>
```

Different Case:

```
<td colspan="2" valign="top">                                <h5>La Redoute</h5>
<p><a href="http://ad.zanox.com/ppc/?17274717C1346468123T" target="_blank"><img src="http://ad.zanox.com/ppv/?17274717C1346468123" alt="Aprovecha nuestra completa y exclusiva oferta de canastilla.5 piezas y una bolsa cambiador de regalo.¡Descúbrela!" align="bottom" border="0" width="468" height="60" hspace="1"></a></p>
<p>Descubre la nueva colección Bebe y Mama. Aprovecha esta exclusiva oferta de canastilla. 5 piezas y una bolsa cambiador de regalo</p>
<p>PARA CANJEAR TU BONO: Tan solo con entrar desde aquí, conseguirás esta estupenda oferta*</p>
<hr size="1"> </td>
```

Basically if there is `<script>` or not, the first `<p>` doen't have same height margin/padding (still don't konw)

Any idea? thanks!

Comment: post the generated html and tell us what you want to select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the same style to all `<p>` tags via:

```
$("p").css(...);
```

You can add a style to the first `<p>` tag via:

```
$("p:first").css(...);
```

(see [:first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) for more info).

In general the [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) page helps you identify far more than just `#id` or `.class`.

Answer (score 2):

try to find some element in your html which you can identify and then identify the sub elements relative to this one...

example:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <div id='content'>
       <div> some advetisement </div>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

this styles the id="content"-div :

```
#content {
 font-weight: bold;
 }
```

and this styles all other divs beneath it:

```
#content div {
 border: 1px solid red
}
```

if this is not enough, you have to use javascript in order to modify your DOM and add styles directly to the element.

Comment: Since the OP is using jQuery, the powerful jQuery selectors and .css method might be enough.